# Setting spray connection limits

Tags: scala, akka, spray

We are currently porting a tomcat application to a spray/scala one.

Our old application has a setup like this:

```
<Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        maxThreads="1000"
        maxConnections="10000"
        processorCache="500"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        redirectPort="8443" />
```

In out new application we'd like to set the equivalent of maxThreads/maxConnections in spray.

I saw the spray reference.conf file (below), and am wondering if these are indeed the correct settings to change?
Or should I rather be configuring the actor that is doing the runRoute?
Or Both?

I did find the low "max-connections = 4" default a bit strange, if that is indeed the server connection limit.

```
host-connector {
# The maximum number of parallel connections that an `HttpHostConnector`
# is allowed to establish to a host. Must be greater than zero.
max-connections = 4

# The maximum number of times an `HttpHostConnector` attempts to repeat
# failed requests (if the request can be safely retried) before
# giving up and returning an error.
max-retries = 5

# Configures redirection following.
# If set to zero redirection responses will not be followed, i.e. they'll be returned to the user as is.
# If set to a value > zero redirection responses will be followed up to the given number of times.
# If the redirection chain is longer than the configured value the first redirection response that is
# is not followed anymore is returned to the user as is.
max-redirects = 0

# If this setting is enabled, the `HttpHostConnector` pipelines requests
# across connections, otherwise only one single request can be "open"
# on a particular HTTP connection.
pipelining = off

# The time after which an idle `HttpHostConnector` (without open
# connections) will automatically terminate itself.
# Set to `infinite` to completely disable idle timeouts.
idle-timeout = 30 s

# Modify to tweak client settings for this host-connector only.
client = ${spray.can.client}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings you are referring to are spray-client settings not spray-server settings.

```
host-connector {    max-connections = 4 }
```

It means if you want to write a spray app that connects to some external HTTP server, you won't be able to create more than 4 connections simultaneously to a specific host.

There is no direct equivalent to **maxThreads**/**maxConnections** in Spray. Because Spray is built on top of Akka Actors. Akka Actors use Dispatchers and Execution Contexts to process messages. The default dispatcher in Spray for Http Listener (the actor that processes HTTP requests) is :

```
listener-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
```

You can read about default dispatcher [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html)

There is no direct way to specify **maxThreads** in Spray because default akka dispatcher is based on top **fork-join-executor** which is leveraging multi-core architecture as much as possible.

To specify **maxConnections** you have to modify source code of [HttpListener](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/server/HttpListener.scala) :

```
case x: Tcp.Bound if(maxConnections()) ⇒ //handle max connections use case
```